# PHP adding the value 1 to a position in an string and replace

Tags: php, function

I want to replace a letter with another character and also add 1 value more.
I mean the values are dynamic

For example I have `H9` ,i want to replace as `G10` .

Similarly...

- `H2` as `G3`
- `H6` as `G7`

Is it possible to use `str_replace()` for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I got this one which works for me:

```
$old_string = "H2";
$new_string = "G" . (substr($old_string, 1) + 1);
echo $new_string;
```

Works fine for me. This is just for one value, but i guess you can loop through an array too, just have to modify the values like this

```
foreach($old_values as $v) {
    $new_values[] = "G" . (substr($v, 1) + 1);
}
```

So you could save all the values into the $new_string array

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/str_replace)

Use

```
$new = array("G10", "G3", "G7");
$old   = array("H9", "H2", "H6");
$string = str_replace($old, $new, $string);
```

where `$string` is your original string.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php 
$str = "H25";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
$str = str_replace($matches['0']['0'], $matches['0']['0']+1, $str, $count);
echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### More simpler way... (Generalized Solution)

```
<?php
$str='G10';
preg_match('!\d+!', $str, $digit); //<---- Match the number
$str = substr($str,0,1); //<--- Grab the first char & increment it in the second line
echo ++$str.($digit[0]+1); //"prints" H11
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/122372)